# ¿Conectar mysql con apache spark mediante python?

Tags: python, mysql, apache-spark

Estoy empezando a usar `spark` para unos problemas de respuesta de datos que tenemos desde `mysql`. He consumido unas tablas que exporté con `phpmyadmin` a `son` pero quiero conectarme directamente a mi localhost para consumir la base de datos del servidor local. No tengo idea de como hacerlo. ¿Alguien ha hecho algo similar?

Comment: son? quieres decir json